# Pandas apply string format using multiple columns

Tags: pandas, string, apply

I have the following dataframe with two columns:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'fname': ['john', 'mike'], 
                          'col2': ['my name is {name}, and today is {day}', 'my name is {name}, and today is {day}']},
                           index=pd.Series([1, 2], name='index'))

      fname                                   col2
index
1      john  my name is {name}, and today is {year}
2      mike  my name is {name}, and today is {year}
```

How do I replace the `{name}` in `col2` so that it gets replaced with whatever is in `fname`? the `yaer` can stay constant at 2022.

```
      fname                                   col2
index
1      john  my name is john, and today is 2022
2      mike  my name is mike, and today is 2022
```

I've tried the following:

```
data.applymap(lambda x: x.format(year=2022))
```

but it's giving me `KeyError: 'name'` since I need to replace the name also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean:

```
data.apply(lambda x: x['col2'].format(name=x['name'], year=2022), axis=1)
```

you can also do:

```
[s.format(name=name, year=2022) for s,name in zip(data['col2'], data['col1'])]
```